# Как в Python программно создать новую базу данных и выполнить в ней скрипт?

Tags: sqlite3, python-2.7

Всем доброго времени суток!

Что имеем:

1. Python 2.7
2. Скрипт для создания базы данных

Что нужно:

1. Создать новую базу данных (sqlite3) прямо в коде Python, уточняю именно НОВУЮ, подключаться к созданным через `sqlite3.connect()` я умею, да и интернет пестрит подобными примерами.
2. Выполнить в ней имеющийся скрипт, который создаст все таблички и т.д. и т.п. Проблема со скриптом следующая: во всех примерах работы с базой, которые встречал используют `cursor.execute` (Текст запроса), метод `execute` не позволяет выполнять пакетные запросы, т.е. один запрос это одно действие, скрипт так не запустить

Ну что, знатоки Python-а, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

З.Ы. Заранее спасибо откликнувшимся!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `sqlite3.connect()`
2. `Cursor.executescript(sql_script).`

Пример:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.executescript("""
    create table person(
        firstname,
        lastname,
        age
    );

    create table book(
        title,
        author,
        published
    );

    insert into book(title, author, published)
    values (
        'Dirk Gently''s Holistic Detective Agency',
        'Douglas Adams',
        1987
    );
    """)
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое. Единственный вопрос: Если база уже существвует, то при вызове connect() выполнится подключение и в ней уже будут таблицы, и повторно скриптом они уже не создадутся, как это можно обойти, или только удалять их запросами?

Comment: возможно, Вам понравиться такой синтаксис

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
     ...
    );

он создаст таблицу, если ее нет. А если таблица есть, то ничего плохого не произойдет.

Comment: А не подскажите как сохранить базу данных созданую таким способом sqlite3.connect(":memory:")? Я имею ввиду в виде файла на жестком диске.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3.connect() создаст базу если ее нет.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы база сохранилась в файл, нужно использовать

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('name.db')
```

Затем cursor:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Затем `executescript('any script')`. При этом повторное обращение к базе по имени `sqlite.connect('name.db')` создаст только подключение, но не новую базу (если будете из других файлов, например, к ней стучаться).
В конце `connection.close()`.